# Javascript: What's the algorithmic performance of 'splice'?

Tags: javascript, performance

That is, would I be better suited to use some kind of tree or skip list data structure if I need to be calling this function a lot for individual array insertions?

Comment: Test it! That's the best way to answer this question...

Comment: What's a good way to test this?

Comment: If JavaScript’s arrays are really arrays, it’s O(n).

Comment: In which case, I would be better suited with a different data structure, right?

Comment: @Gumbo: IE used a hash algorithm for arrays, if i recall correctly.

Comment: @Hamster: In case `splice` removes or adds some elements, you will need to create a new array with the new length and copy at least all elements before the deletion/insertion position and all elements after that position; that makes it O(n). Only the in-place replacement will just take O(1) for every replaced element.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yeah, I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: @Gumbo: JavaScript's arrays are not really arrays (they're just maps with string keys that are [primarily] all-numeric and a magic `length` property), so it's totally implementation-dependent.

Comment: They keys would still have to be changed individually from the inserted element on, though.  Still O(n) I believe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might consider whether you want to use an object instead; all JavaScript objects (including `Array` instances) are (highly-optimized) sets of key/value pairs with an optional prototype An implementation *should* (note I don't say "does") have a reasonable performance hashing algorithm. *(**Update**: That was in 2010. Here in 2018, objects are **highly** optimized on all significant JavaScript engines.)*

Aside from that, the performance of `splice` is going to vary a **lot** between implementations (e.g., vendors). This is one reason why "don't optimize prematurely" is even more appropriate advice for JavaScript applications that will run in multiple vendor implementations (web apps, for instance) than it is even for normal programming. Keep your code well modularized and address performance issues if and when they occur.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a good rule of thumb, based on tests done in Chrome, Safari and Firefox: Splicing a single value into the middle of an array is roughly **half as fast** as pushing/shifting a value to one end of the array. (Note: Only tested on an array of size 10,000.)

http://jsperf.com/splicing-a-single-value

That's pretty fast. So, it's unlikely that you need to go so far as to implement another data structure in order to squeeze more performance out.

**Update**: As eBusiness points out in the comments below, the test performs an expensive copy operation along with each `splice`, `push`, and `shift`, which means that it understates the difference in performance. Here's a revised test that avoids the array copying, so it should be much more accurate: http://jsperf.com/splicing-a-single-value/19

Comment: Actually, it's entirely dependent on the length of the array. If you change to a 100,000 element array, then splicing a value into the middle is 95% slower than adding a value on the end, as measured by your jsperf test. That's because inserting in the middle is O(n) in the size of the array, while inserting at the end can be O(1).

Comment: -1 That jsperf test is polluted by copying an array, it's mostly measuring the time it takes to create a whole new 10000 item array.

Comment: @eBusiness Please elaborate on your claim. Where in the tests does the array get copied?

Comment: @TrevorBurnham You run `getArr()` within the test, in `getArr()` you run `arr.slice(0)`, which is shorthand for duplicating an array. So your benchmark is doing one full duplication of a 10000 element array and a single operation on an array.

Comment: @eBusiness Ah, I see your point! So the test actually understates the difference in performance between `splice` and `push`/`shift`. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham And you should really remove the old text, the conclusions drawn from an incorrect benchmark are probably not what readers are after.

Comment: I think you need to compare unshift instead of shift (shift remove first value, unshift append value): https://jsperf.com/splicing-a-single-value/66

Answer (score 1):

Move single value

```js
// tmp = arr[1][i];
// arr[1].splice(i, 1); // splice is slow in FF
// arr[1].splice(end0_1, 0, tmp);

 tmp = arr[1][i];
 ii = i;
 while (ii<end0_1)
  {
  arr[1][ii] = arr[1][++ii];
cycles++;
  }
 arr[1][end0_1] = tmp;
```