# How to add items into an Array if they sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var mes_dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
```

I'd like to know if is there somehow to create a new array only if the sum of them are less than a global array using a loop or something, example

```
var dia = 122;
var dia_new = [31, 28, 31, 30]; //This because they sum less than the given var (dia).
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: question is :dia_new can be lots of choices,for example:[30,30,30,30] also works,,,

Comment: Thanks, but I should use the items in dia array to create new, with a loop or something, of course... if there is someway to do

Comment: The months in the `dia_new` array are sequential right?

Comment: Is `dia` an array or a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var mes_dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  var dia = 122;
  var total = 0;
  var newarray = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i < mes_dias.length && (total + mes_dias[i]) <= dia; i++) {
    newarray.push(mes_dias[i]);
    total = total + mes_dias[i];
    console.log(newarray);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use a Javascript `for-loop` and check the count in every iteration.
- If the count is lesser than `dia` then push that number into the `array`.

---

```
for(var i = 0; i < mes_dias.length && (count + mes_dias[i] < dia); i++)
```

```js
var mes_dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var dia = 122;
var count = 0;
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < mes_dias.length && (count + mes_dias[i] < dia); i++) {
  count += mes_dias[i];
  array.push(mes_dias[i]);
}
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

**if `dia` is an array of numbers, and its `sum` is the max days for the new array:**

*The `reduce` function will sum the elements in `array_dia`.*

```
var dia = array_dias.reduce((a, n) => a += n, 0);
```

```js
var mes_dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var array_dias = [30, 30, 31, 31];

var dia = array_dias.reduce((a, n) => a += n, 0);
console.log(dia)

var count = 0;
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < mes_dias.length && (count + mes_dias[i] < dia); i++) {
  count += mes_dias[i];
  array.push(mes_dias[i]);
}
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: No idea why anybody downvoted it. That's raging... A comment: you do `count + mes_dias[i]` twice, which is not DRY. I would advise get it out of the loop's condition and do a clean `break`

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` your array into a new array:

```
let mes_dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

let dia = 120;

let dia_new = mes_dias.reduce( (dia_acc, dias) => {
    dia -= dias;
    if (dia >= 0)
        dia_acc.push(dias);
    return dia_acc;
}, []);
```

---

EDIT 1: Based on [Angel Politis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716626/8122487), another elegant solution can be:

```
let dia_new = mes_dias.slice(0, mes_dias.findIndex( (dias) => (dia -= dias) < 0));
```

---

EDIT 2: Based on [Ele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716372/8122487), this way offers same, if not better, performance and is more readable in my view. Remember, in worst case scenario we loop 12 times.

```
let array = [],
    sum = 0;
// Add days until they sum to more than 'dia'
for(let i = 0; i < mes_dias.length; ++i) {
    sum += mes_dias[i];
    if (sum > dia)
        break;
    array.push(mes_dias[i]);
}
```

Comment: Here you’re looping the whole array.

Comment: @Ele: correct. So what? Ever heard of the anti-pattern **premature optimization**? Think twice when you sacrifice readability, maintainability or anything for the supposed sake of performance. Good example:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228110/8122487

Comment: First, I didn’t downvote.  Second, this tiny scenario can be solved with a simple for-loop IMHO.  A for-loop is readable and provide good performance as well.  You don’t need to think about pattern, anti-pattern, Etc to solve this problem.  Nowadays the performance it’s one of the most critical thing you need to pay attention, so if you can avoid poor performance then do it.

Comment: @Ele: no worries about the votes. There are always smart buddies that have no respect for the community's work. I have added how I see your answer can be improved. Doing this, you would have got my vote.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want would be using a loop in which you:

- progressively sum the elements of `mes_dias`.
- cache the index of the last element, if `sum <= dia`.

Then, you can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) to get the portion of the array until the `last` index.

**Snippet:**

```js
var
  arr = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],   // mes_dias
  max = 122,                                                // dia
  last,
  newArr;

/* Iterate over every element of the array until sum > max and save the index. */
for (let i = 0, sum = 0, l = arr.length; i < l && sum <= max; sum += arr[++i]) {
  last = i;
}

/* Get the portion of the array until the index. */
newArr = arr.slice(0, last);

/* Log the result. */
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Nice idea to find index and use `slice`. You could also use `findIndex` to get the index. I'm just not fond of doing the work in the loop's condition instead of the loop's block.